# "Со своей стороны" — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Со своей стороны(,) Иванов поблагодарил главу правительства за теплый прием...
Нужна ли зпт в скобках? В Инете противоречивые примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без контекста трудно дать однозначный ответ. Скорее всего, запятая нужна. Если, например, глава правительства поздравил Иванова с юбилеем, то тогда нужно поставить запятую (данное высказывание связано по смыслу с предшествующим):

**Со своей стороны, Иванов поблагодарил главу правительства.**

Вот что говорит справочник:

> [СО СВОЕЙ СТОРОНЫ, вводное выражение и члены предложения](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=696)
>
> 1. Вводное выражение. Указывает на то, что данное высказывание связано по смыслу с предшествующим. То же, что 'в свою очередь'. Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах см. в Приложении 2.
>      Карачунский, со своей стороны, не хотел уступать из принципа, чтобы не показать перед рабочими своей несостоятельности. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Золото. Чичиков, с своей стороны, был очень рад, что поселился на время у такого мирного и смирного хозяина. Н. Гоголь, Мертвые души.
> 2. Члены предложения. Не требуют постановки знаков препинания.
>      Старики до тех пор обдумывали все это каждый про себя, что наконец друг с другом и переговорились, обнялись, обещались дело порядком обработать и принялись о нем хлопотать каждый со своей стороны. А. Пушкин, Барышня-крестьянка. Я со своей стороны и от имени администрации поздравляю вас, товарищ Привалов, с наступающим Новым годом и желаю вам в новом году соответствующих успехов как в работе, так и в личной жизни. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Понедельник начинается в субботу.